# Firefox Setup: how to use existing profile

Tags: firefox, updates, firefox-profile

In order to prepare a classroom for training, I run a Windows batch file which, among other things, runs the Firefox Setup application.

There is an existing profile folder which has everything the way I want it, so I always choose not to restore default settings.

[image: Firefox Installer]

However, when Firefox restarts, it always starts with a new default profile.

I can manually delete the profile and files using the Profile Manager:

[image: Profile Manager]

… but that is tedious for a classroom, especially when I need to do it repeatedly.

Ho can I run the installer and get it to use the existing default profile?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `default-release` is the one created by the upgrade process, and `default` profile is the one you want to use after the upgrade, just add one more line of code to your batch file:

```
firefox.exe -P default
```

This starts Firefox using the profile called `default`.

It seems Firefox stores all profile names, paths and which one to use during startup in `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini`, maybe you can do this:

```
1. Backup the above file prior to upgrade 
2. Restore the file after upgrade
```

If you do this, the actual profile folder would still be there, maybe you can remove it by something like `rmdir /Q /S %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default-relase`.

Comment: I have tried that, but it retains the `default-release` profile, and will use it next time unless I always select the old profile. I was hoping to permanently use the original profile, which I have been doing by deleting the new one.

Comment: @Manngo updated answer. Note that I didn't verify the method myself. I believe there's a good chance it'll work.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I had mixed success. I will try again on Monday, and will let you know how that works. Thanks.